# Service Bus 1.1 and Relay Binding

Tags: iis, azure, servicebus

I am trying to use Service Bus 1.1 for Windows Server to access WCF services hosted on IIS 7.5 via client but not able to do so.

I have tried all the small help provided on MSDN portal but not getting through. Can you please float this query on you community seek the below-
1.  Working sample for WCF, SB for Windows Server, Hosted on IIS and not on Console App.
2.  Any documentation or eBook that I can refer, actually I am designing a SOA Application that where we are planning to have a on premises Service Bus. Please note I am using SB 1.1 for Windows server and not the Azure Service Bus.

All the samples listed on internet are not working with SB 1.1 on Windows 7 or Win 2008 R2.

I thing the main issue is Relay bindings are not supported on SB 1.1 for Windows server, can you please confirm, on if this is the case how to communicate with the Services  hosted on IIS via SB 1.1 on Premises on Windows Server 2012

Any help appreciated.

Thanks
Gaurav Parmar

Answer (score 0):

Service Bus Relay is not available for Service Bus Server. Features are described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn282142.aspx. Note that only queues and topics are supported.